# How do I compile/check all files in a directory with Rust?

Tags: rust

What I tried so far:

1. `rustc FILE`, but rustc only wants to compile files which have a `main` function
2. `cargo build`, but this does not check files which are not yet used.
3. `cargo test` seems to check all files, but it also runs the tests

So I am searching for a mix of 2. and 3. where it checks all the files, but does not run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rust, contrarily to C or C++, the compilation unit is the crate, not the file.

Given this, the compiler automatically seeks all files referenced from the first file you gave it, it is the only way it can work.

Yet, if you really want to check some files without including them in your project with `mod` statements, you can compile each of then individually as libs :

```
rustc --crate-type rlib FILE
```